# List through all files and find a specific file location

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to list through .xml files in a folder. For that I did:

```
find . -name *.xml
```

The result will be file location, which I should do a `cat` and do a grep for the text `test`, if `test` is present then print the file location, else skip.

To begin with I tried:

```
find . -name *.xml | xargs cat * | grep test
```

but this prints the matching line, but not the file location. I tried `-b`, `-l` commands with grep to get the file location, but it doesn't work.

And `cat` only prints the file in the given location but not recursively accessing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find . -name *.xml -exec grep -l test {} +
```

This will execute `grep -l test` on all files found by find.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `globstar` shell option to enable subdirectory globbing:

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -l 'test' **/*.xml
```

When `globstar` is enabled, `**` matches "all files and zero or more subdirectories" (see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)).